# How to zip arrays with jq and a custom zipping function

Tags: jq

I have this data:

```json
[
  [
    "USER",
    "TTY",
    "FROM",
    "LOGIN@",
    "IDLE",
    "JCPU",
    "PCPU",
    "WHAT"
  ],
  [
    "lava1",
    "pts/0",
    "157.48.149.102",
    "05:03",
    "31.00s",
    "0.31s",
    "0.31s",
    "-bash"
  ],
  [
    "azureuse",
    "pts/1",
    "157.48.149.102",
    "07:26",
    "0.00s",
    "0.07s",
    "0.05s",
    "w"
  ]
]
```

And I want it as such:

```json
[
  { 
     "USER": "lava1",
     "TTY": "pts/0"
  },
  { 
     "USER": "azureuse",
     "TTY": "pts/1"
  }
]
```

Etc, for all K/V pairs.
So basically
`map {(.[0][..]) : [:1][..]})` - I want to create a mapping between an entry in `.[0]` and it's respective entry in  the remaining `[:..]`

Definitely not valid syntax but I'm hitting my head on how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
jq '.[0] as $cols 
| .[1:] 
| map(. as $row 
  | $cols   
  | with_entries({ "key": .value,"value": $row[.key]}) 
)'
```

Results:

```json
[
  {
    "USER": "lava1",
    "TTY": "pts/0",
    "FROM": "157.48.149.102",
    "LOGIN@": "05:03",
    "IDLE": "31.00s",
    "JCPU": "0.31s",
    "PCPU": "0.31s",
    "WHAT": "-bash"
  },
  {
    "USER": "azureuse",
    "TTY": "pts/1",
    "FROM": "157.48.149.102",
    "LOGIN@": "07:26",
    "IDLE": "0.00s",
    "JCPU": "0.07s",
    "PCPU": "0.05s",
    "WHAT": "w"
  }
]
```

Read more:
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#zip-column-headers-with-their-rows

Comment: Everyone had good answers, but I am going to give this post credit for being most concise and following with a readme

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
jq '.[0] as [$user, $tty] | .[1:] | map({$user:.[0], $tty:.[1]})' input.json
```

Or if you want to pick the columns you want :

```
jq '.[0] as $title
  | [0, 1] as $cols # Pick the first and second columns
  | .[1:] | map(. as $v
              | reduce $cols[] as $i ({}; .[$title[$i]]=$v[$i]))'
```

If you want to select by keys :

```
jq --argjson cols '["USER", "TTY"]' '.[0] as $title
  | ($title | [index($cols[])]) as $indexes
  | .[1:] | map(. as $v
              | reduce $indexes[] as $i ({}; .[$title[$i]]=$v[$i]))' input.json
```

Comment: I was looking for the more generalized approach - hardcoding the keys would be much easier

Answer (score 2):

Zipping automatically (closer to your approach) using the inefficient `transpose` twice:

```bash
transpose | map([{(.[0]): .[1:][]}]) | transpose | map(add)
```

Zipping manually by storing the keys into a variable, then assigning them on the fly:

```bash
.[0] as $keys | .[1:] | map(with_entries(.key |= $keys[.]))
```